# elasticsearch / kibana errors "Data too large, data for [@timestamp] would be larger than limit

Tags: kibana, kibana-4, elasticsearch

On my test ELK cluster, I'm encountering the following error when trying to see data from the last week.

```
Data too large, data for [@timestamp] would be larger than limit
```

The warning about shards failing appears to be misleading because the elasticsearch monitoring tools `kopf` and `head` show that all shards are working properly, and the elastic cluster is green.

[image]

One user in the google group for elasticsearch suggested increasing ram. I've increased my 3 nodes to 8GB each with a 4.7GB heap, but the issue continues. 
I'm generating about 5GB to 25GB of data per day, with a 30 day retention.

Answer (score 59):

Clearing the cache alleviates the symptoms for now.

http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-clearcache.html

Clear a single index

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/_cache/clear'
```

Clear multiple indicies

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/kimchy,elasticsearch/_cache/clear'

curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_cache/clear'
```

Or as suggested by a user in IRC. This one seems to work the best.

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_cache/clear' -d '{ "fielddata": "true" }'
```

*Update*: these errors went away as soon as the cluster was moved to a faster hypervisor

Comment: I ran into the same issues and clearing the cache solved them. I'm not sure if this is something which needs to be done periodically. Thanks!

Comment: This worked! Thanks! Never seen this issue before despite using ES for several years now...very strange.

Comment: Yes, had the same problem and cleared the cache and everything was working again. Upvote and star question.

Comment: Only the last one worked for me, even though I was only querying one of the indices

Comment: @spuder +1, It helped a lot.

Comment: Are you doing this regularly or was it enough to do it once?

Comment: But the question remains, does clearing the cache have to be done periodically or there is a permanent fix such as configuration change that needs to be done to fix it permanently?

Comment: Thanks @spuder  it works..But is it necessary to clear cache to periodically? Why cache becomes full...is there any option to avoid this problem

Comment: The problem magically went away for us. We suspect network/hypervisor performance problems were the root cause.

Comment: also needs `-H "Content-Type: application/json"`

Comment: "[POST /_cache/clear] does not support having a body"

Answer (score 10):

The problem is the memory given to the Elasticsearch by ES_JAVA_OPTS.

Try to give more memory with: ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx2g -Xms2g".

Answer (score 6):

The `_cache` API also supports targeted clearing to the threadpools for fielddata, request, etc. through just normal URI query parameters.

Prototype, see the placeholder `<cache type>`:

```
$ curl -XPOST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    'http://localhost:9200/_cache/clear?<cache type>=true'
```

#### Examples

```
$ curl -XPOST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    'http://localhost:9200/_cache/clear?fielddata=true'
```

```
$ curl -XPOST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    'http://localhost:9200/_cache/clear?request=true'
```

**NOTE:** You can also target specific indexes, substitute below where `<index>`:

```
$ curl -XPOST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    'http://localhost:9200/<index>/_cache/clear?request=true'
```

#### References

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-clearcache.html

Comment: The Content-Type is not necessary if you're not including a body

Answer (score 1):

Clearing the cache didn't work for our cluster. When checking the various nodes using http://x.x.x.x:9200/_cat/indices?v&s=index:desc one was giving the above error and the others had invalid pointer errors. I **restarted the elastic service** on the one giving the rate limit/data too large error. When it came back online there were some unassigned shards, which I fixed by dropping the replication count to a lower number (only need to do this on one of the nodes to change the index settings for the cluster):

```
IFS=$'\n'
for line in $(curl -s 'elastic-search.example.com:9200/_cat/shards' | fgrep UNASSIGNED); do
  INDEX=$(echo $line | (awk '{print $1}'))
  echo start $INDEX
  curl -XPUT "elastic-search.example.com:9200/$INDEX/_settings" -d '{
      "index" : {
        "number_of_replicas" : 1
      }
    }
    '
done

# Check shard/cluster status (may take some time to rebalance):
# http://elastic-search.example.com:9200/_cat/shards?v&s=index:desc
# http://elastic-search.example.com:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
```

Also https://discuss.elastic.co/t/data-too-large/32141 seems to mention it may be an issue with the size of the JVM heap.