# Creating a "Brand Lovers" segment in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got an ElasticSearch index that records hits, with a `time` and `token` field, unique to each user. I'd like to know, for the last x days, how many unique tokens I have that have had 15 or more hits. ("Brand Lovers" in marketing-speak.)

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Added a generic query, if you want a working query, please provide few sample documents

Answer (score 0):

You can use the range query with terms aggregation to get required results

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "hits": {
                            "gte": 15
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "time": {
                            "gte": "now-1d/d",
                            "lt": "now"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "distinct_tokens": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "tokens"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure why but this seems to use a significant amount of memory, and the query cannot complete. `[parent] Data too large, data for [<reused_arrays>] would be [1328218080/1.2gb], which is larger than the limit of [1020054732/972.7mb], real usage: [1029342112/981.6mb], new bytes reserved: [298875968/285mb], usages [request=298888256/285mb, fielddata=411157872/392.1mb, in_flight_requests=1803362/1.7mb, model_inference=0/0b, eql_sequence=0/0b, accounting=14469608/13.7mb]`

Comment: @JasonNorwood-Young how many documents you have and how much heap you assigned to your Elasticsearch process?

Comment: About 500m. I'm going to try increase the heap size and clear the cache as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810531/elasticsearch-kibana-errors-data-too-large-data-for-timestamp-would-be-la

Comment: @JasonNorwood-Young, sure 500 Mb is very less and keep us posted :)

Comment: Oh, sorry, 500 million records, not MB. The index is 320.4GB big.

Comment: wow, 500 M documents, and Elasticsearch heap size on a node shouldn't cross 30 GB

Comment: @JasonNorwood-Young any update on it?

Comment: I've figured out I need to build an ElasticSearch pipeline aggregation to achieve what I want. I increased heap size to 16GB, which helped, but the transaction still fails about half the time. I'll look at adding another server too. I should get to it next week and will give a full update!